# How i can customize the reset password validation message and also form validation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

*Hi, my default language of the web template is Persian and currently,
I saved the translate of languages in the database. so I need to translate all form validation message. I edited my `RegisterController` validation message like this and it works correctly.*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Helpers\Translate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default, this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $messages = [
            'name.required' => Translate::translate('Name_is_required.',session('locale')),
            'name.max' => Translate::translate('The_name_may_not_be_greater_than_255_characters.',session('locale')),
            'email.required' => Translate::translate('Email_is_required.',session('locale')),
            'email.email' => Translate::translate('Type_valid_email.',session('locale')),
            'email.unique' => Translate::translate('The_email_has_already_been_taken.',session('locale')),
            'mobile.required' => Translate::translate('Mobile_is_required.',session('locale')),
            'mobile.max' => Translate::translate('The_mobile_may_not_be_greater_than_15_characters.',session('locale')),
            'mobile.regex' => Translate::translate('Type_valid_contact_number.',session('locale')),
            'password.required' => Translate::translate('Password_is_required.',session('locale')),
            'password.min' => Translate::translate('The_password_must_be_at_least_6_characters.',session('locale')),
            'password.confirmed' => Translate::translate('The_password_confirmation_does_not_match.',session('locale')),
        ];
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'mobile' => ['required', 'string', 'max:15','regex:/^(00|\+|0)[1-9]{1}([0-9][\s]*){6,16}$/'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ],$messages);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

*I also want to change the `ForgotPasswordController` validation message but i can't change and it not working and not showing any error*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Helpers\Translate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $messages = [
            'email.required' => Translate::translate('Email_is_required.',session('locale')),
            'email.email' => Translate::translate('Type_valid_email.',session('locale')),
        ];
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        ],$messages);
    }
}
```

*how I can change the validation message of reset password ??? I'm newbie in laravel*

**can any one help me?**

Comment: I've added wrong answer at first look at the on I've recently added, I think this should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SendsPasswordResetEmails` trait is used in `ForgotPasswordController` and it has a method `validateEmail` that deal with validation rule and its message. If you want to change validation and it's message then overwrite both function in `ForgotPasswordController`.

Change your code like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Helpers\Translate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    /**
     * Validate the email for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, 
            [
                'email' => 'required|email'
            ],
            $messages = [
                'email.required' => Translate::translate('Email_is_required.',session('locale')),
                'email.email' =>  Translate::translate('Type_valid_email.',session('locale')),
            ]);
    }
}
```

I hope you will understand.

**UPDATE**

In the same way, `ResetsPasswords` trait is used by `ResetPasswordController` so you can override the function of traits in the controller.

Just put following functions in the `ResetPasswordController`

```
/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function rules()
{
    // If you have further fields and rules you can add in following array.
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation error messages.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function validationErrorMessages()
{
    return [
         // Here write your custom validation error messages
    ];
}
```

I hope you will understand. If any confusion feel free to ask.

Comment: it has the error `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController::validateEmail() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of `

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin I've added `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` on the top did you added that in your code ?

Comment: now. I also want to change `ResetPasswordController` how I do that it has any trait method?

Comment: are you there. does `ResetPasswordController` has any trait method?

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin Yes of course, t is `ResetsPasswords`, If you want I can add further code in above answer

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin it would be better to ask separate question since issue is different, any way I will add in above answer. Wait few minutes.

Comment: @gihandilanka it's pleasure

Answer (score -1):

These messages management with locale/translate files.
You can change validation messages via `resource/lang/validation.php`

Comment: my translate isn't in the file. my language is in database